# count each item in an array using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanna achieve one function using AngularJs, like this [image: please click here to see what i want], 
  each time click one of ingredient the selected list have changed and add one more ingredient and show the number, if repeat to click one ingredient just change the amount of this ingredient

```
 here is my html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addIngredientCtrl">
    <div class="ingredient-list">
        <h4>INGREDIENT:</h4>
        <ul ng-repeat="items in item.recipe.IngredientMapping">
            <li class="ingredient-list-style">
            <img src="http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/api/AngularJs/images/plus.png" class="plus-size" ng-click="addIngredient(items.Ingredient.name)">
            {{items.quantity}} &nbsp; {{items.Unit.name}} &nbsp;{{items.Ingredient.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="selected-list-box">
        <div class="selected-list">
            <h4>Selected List</h4>
            <div>
            <ul ng-repeat="selectedItem in selectedItem track by $index">
                <li>
                    {{selectedItem}} 
                    <li ng-repeat="(c, n) in results"> {{c}} shows {{n}} times</li>
                </li>
            </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

here is my js

```
 myApp.controller('addIngredientCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.selectedItem=Array();
$scope.addIngredient= function(param){

    $scope.selectedItem.push(param);

    console.log($scope.selectedItem);

     $scope.results = {};
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedItem.length; i++) {
        var selected = $scope.$scope.selectedItem[i];
        if(selected) {
         if ($scope.results.hasOwnProperty(selected)) {
         $scope.results[selected]++;
         } else {
            $scope.results[selected] = 1;
             }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had $scope twice in your code on line

```
 var selected = $scope.$scope.selectedItem[i];
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('addIngredientCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.item = {
   recipe:{
     IngredientMapping:[
       {quantity:1,Unit:{name:'kg'},Ingredient:{name:"onion"}}
     ]
   }
};
$scope.selectedItem=Array();
$scope.addIngredient= function(param){
console.log($scope.selectedItem);
    $scope.selectedItem.push(param);

   
 $scope.results = {};
     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedItem.length; i++) {
        var selected = $scope.selectedItem[i];
        if(selected) {
         if ($scope.results.hasOwnProperty(selected)) {
         $scope.results[selected]++;
         } else {
            $scope.results[selected] = 1;
             }

        }
    }

    
  }
});
```

```html
<style>
  .plus-size{height:16px;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addIngredientCtrl">
    <div class="ingredient-list">
        <h4>INGREDIENT:</h4>
        <ul ng-repeat="items in item.recipe.IngredientMapping">
            <li class="ingredient-list-style">
            <img src="http://164.132.196.117/chop_dev/api/AngularJs/images/plus.png" class="plus-size" ng-click="addIngredient(items.Ingredient.name)">
            {{items.quantity}} &nbsp; {{items.Unit.name}} &nbsp;{{items.Ingredient.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="selected-list-box">
        <div class="selected-list">
            <h4>Selected List</h4>
            <div>
            <ul ng-repeat="selectedItem in selectedItem track by $index">
                <li>
                    {{selectedItem}} 
                    <li ng-repeat="(c, n) in results"> {{c}} shows {{n}} times</li>
                </li>
            </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: yes , i figured out my mistake right now when I checked it back, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I havent tested. But it should work. I have used `array.reduce` method.

```
var arr=[];
function arrayCount (array_elements,search) {
       var count = array_elements.reduce(function(n, val) {
           return  n + (val === search);
       }, 0);
       return count;
 }

   $scope.selectedItem.forEach(function(val){
        arr.push({val:val,count:arrayCount($scope.selectedItem,val)})
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I knew where a mistake is

Comment: very simple and clean code and I tried this, it is working, thank you so much

Comment: Thanks@Agnes for compliment. :)

Comment: Hi @Ved, I have been confused about function arrayCount, especially the line "return n + ( val ==== search);", can u explain that for me？ Thanks

Comment: @Agnes. is it not working for you? Or you want to understand?